# Remove certain views of layout with loop

Tags: java, android, loops, layout

I'm dynamically creating views with a method which I add to my layout. 
I'm trying to implement another button which is supposed to access the layout and remove them by using a loop, but my app seems to crash consistently.
 I'm attempting to do it with a loop because I don't want to remove all of the views through the methods `removeAllViews()` or `removeAllViewsInLayout()`.

```
public void RemoveViews() {

    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintId);

    // I'd like to keep a text view and a button, but remove the rest.

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int textView1Id = textView1.getId();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    int fabId = fab.getId();

    int count = layout.getChildCount();

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        View childPos = layout.getChildAt(i);
        int childId = layout.getChildAt(i).getId();

        // Here I try to detect whether the child is the text view or button.

        if(textView1Id == childId || fabId == childId) {}
        else {
            // The line below causes the crashing.
            layout.removeView(childPos);

            // This one also crashes:
            //layout.removeViewAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintId"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="onClick_textView1"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text1"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think this is the logcat of the error (FATAL EXCEPTION: main):

```
2018-12-31 14:57:33.004 7507-7507/com.example.test4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test4, PID: 7507
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24774)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24774) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.test4.MainActivity.RemoveKeyboardList(MainActivity.java:115)
    at com.example.test4.MainActivity.onClick_textView1(MainActivity.java:64)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24774) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Basically, I'd like to know how to do this without having the app crashing, and whether there is a better way to remove multiple views from a layout.

//

**Solution**

Thanks to the suggestion by Anmol, to add the dynamically created views in a separate layout, I achieved what I was looking for, though I couldn't make it work with a loop. I have included my solution here because <s>it's a bit different from his</s>, though I accepted his answer. Sorry, it's the same, but I have included all the steps on how to implement it. Please give credit where it's due.

**Step 1:**
Add *another layout* to be included in activity_main.xml. I named it `dynamic_content.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dynamic_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Step 2:** Include the new layout in `activity_main.xml`.

```
// Add the line below anywhere as far as I know.
<include layout="@layout/dynamic_content" />
```

**Step 3:** Include all dynamically created views in the new layout only.

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_content);

// Create new text views, buttons, etc.
layout.addView(newTextView);
```

**Step 4:** Create the function to remove them.

```
public void RemoveViews() {
    ConstraintLayout dynamic = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_content);
    dynamic.removeAllViews();
}
```

**Step 5:** Add the function to a button.

```
public void onClick_buttonName(View v)
{
    RemoveViews();
}
```

And it's **done - enjoy!**

Comment: this is because you are doing `for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {` - if you remove some child views you will not be able to get child views at positions [0..count-1]

Comment: please write in your question the error message in logcat!

Comment: @Thelouras Hello, sorry about that, but it's really long. Is it necessary?

Comment: you have `NullPointerException` right? so see my comment above - this is from `getChildAt` docs: *"Returns
View the view at the specified position or **null if the position does not exist** within the group"*

Comment: @pskink Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I tried to change it to `for(int i=1;i<count;i++) {`, but it still crashes...

Comment: Yeah , which is the exception ?

Comment: ok, so lets say you have 10 child views (`count` == 10) and you removed 3 first children (when `i` variable was 0, 1 and 2) - can you still use getChildAt(7) or getChildAt(8) or getChildAt(9)?

Comment: @Thelouras I think I found the logcat part for the problem, please see the new edit.

Comment: @pskink Okay, that makes sense. Perhaps it could work if I could remove by Id rather than position? But I've yet to find a method that can do that.

Comment: So this is the problem "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference"

Comment: I have a recommendation that create a separate container on top of your layout(MatchParent) to add all the dynamic view's and do `removeAllView()` on that container it's the most efficient way to handle this type of usecase.
@ErlendK.H.

Comment: @pskink I tried this: `int childId = layout.getChildAt(i).getId(); View childView = findViewById(childId); layout.removeView(childView);` However, it crashed again... Perhaps not all of the views have an id?

Comment: @pskink Thanks, but unfortunately they didn't work. The first one crashed the second time, while the other crashed on the first.

`View childPos = layout.getChildAt(i); if(textView1Id != childId || fabId != childId) {layout.removeView(childPos); count--;} else { i++;}}`

Comment: Oh okay, I'd like to add an if statement which preserves the two child views I have mentioned. I apologize if my knowledge is a bit limited. Do you have a suggestion to how I should rephrase it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your use-case you can add a containerLayout in your layout and add all dynamic view to that container and when you want to remove the dynamic view's just do below.

```
public void AddViewToContainer(View view){

    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerfordynamic_view);

    layout.addView(view);

}

public void RemoveViews() {

    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerfordynamic_view);

    layout.removeAllViews();

}
```

And Second option is do removeAllView() on your layout and add your editText and Fab button again,

But this should not be preferred as currently you have only two View to retain but if the list grows that is too much overhead for the simple operation so better go with the first solution which is easy to manage and manipulate also.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Anmol, thank you for your suggestion. If I understand correctly, do you recommend me to create another layout (xml) and then add include that layout in activity_main.xml? Perhaps it could work, though at the moment I use the textview from the main layout to organize the dynamically created views with top margin. I'll get back to you if I try it.

Comment: Yes i am asking you to add a constraint Layout(or any other based on your use case) in your `activity_main.xml` with parent of the container being `R.id.constraintId` keep it as a `matchParent`  you can still  organise the container wrt(with respect to) to textView and all dynamic View's wrt to the container i believe this is the best approach. and access it while adding and removing the dynamic view.

@ErlendK.H.

Comment: @ErlendK.H. if you will share your main Activity xml i will edit it and Update my answer.

Comment: I have included the main_activity.xml now, please see the new edit.

Comment: Ah, it worked perfectly! Do you mind if I accept your answer as well as include the solution in my question?

Comment: @ErlendK.H.sure as you wish Glad to help :D

Answer (score 2):

Use [core-ktx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) `iterator()` method

```
import androidx.core.view.iterator

private fun removeViews(layout: ConstraintLayout) {
    val textView1Id = layout.textView1.id
    val fabId = layout.fab.id
    layout.iterator().also { iterator ->
        iterator.forEach { view ->
            if (textView1Id != childId && fabId = childId) {
                iterator.remove()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you layout container as a ViewGroup and loop through it:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

for(int index=0; index<((ViewGroup)viewGroup).getChildCount(); ++index) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)viewGroup).getChildAt(index);
    nextChild.setVisibility(View.GONE); // This will somehow remove the view from Ui
    viewGroup.removeView(nextChild); // Or really remove it to be wiped out of memory
}
```

Comment: Hello Malv, thank you for your suggestion. I tried it, and while it doesn't cause a crash and successfully removes the views, for some reason it takes multiple clicks to do it. The layout got initially 23 children in which I'd like to keep 2. After first click, 12 remain, then 7, then 4, 3, and finally 2. I'm not sure why it does this though.

Answer (score 0):

Views has three states Visible, GONE, Invisible....
Please set view state to GONE it will be wiped out of memory however if ur intention is to just hide the view simply set it invisible....

Comment: By keeping views gone will not wipe out of memory. Gone does not mean it will not be loaded in memory but will not visible. To wipe out the views from memory one need to call removeView().

Answer (score 0):

You get NullPointerException because you try to access views which dont't exsist anymore. When you remove view, you have one view less in your ConstraintLayout, but your count variable stays the same.

So you have to calculate number of views in loop iteration.

And you have decrement i every time you delete view, because when you delete view all views after that one shifts for one element back.

```
for(int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if(textView1Id == childId || fabId == childId) {}
    else {
        layout.removeView(childPos);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I try to add `layout.removeView(childPos--);`, but it says that the operator "--" cannot be applied to "android.view.View".

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You have to decrement i in case of removing view. I edited the answer.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately the app still crashes.